# Page filter doesn't work in edit mode

Tags: 2013, list-view, filter, connected-web-parts

In my library I have the document id service turned on. So each new document gets an unchanging id. That is working.

I then have some other documents which are related to a given page. I've created a custom content type that included a **RelatedDocID** field as part of the metadata associated with that document.

On the page I added a list view of my library and want to filter it to only show the documents that have RelatedDocIDs which match the DocumentID of the current page.

I added a **Page Field Filter** to the page and set it up to get the **Document ID Value**. I then set up the list view connection to get the value from my filter.

And all this works!

The problem is that when I edit the page, the filter doesn't work and the list view webpart shows everything.

How can I fix it so the list view web part is filtered both in regular and edit views?

And if there isn't a way to get the Page Field Filter webpart to do this, is there some other way I can filter a list view webpart?